# raw_input or input does not complete by new line

Tags: python, input

I am using Python language to program Cedrat Flux (a finite element software). Whatever Python commands I tried yet was O.K. But now I am trying to receive user information from command line using `raw_input()` or `input()`. Unfortunately despite normal Python it does not stop receiving characters by pressing New Line or Enter key.
The only way to stop is to close Flux!

Comment: You haven't really given us enough information. Can you include an example of a script which you should think but doesn't? Even better would be if you could reduce the problem down to a minimal counterexampl.e

Comment: This behavior is probably related to Flux's Python shell. You should contact their support department. Unfortunately, even a demo version of Flux is hard to get, so it's hard even for Python experts to help here. In the meantime, try reading with `sys.stdin.readline()`. Does that work?

Comment: @katrielalex I think the problem is aptly phrased, and quite frankly this is the best question I've ever seen from a new user. Sample code is implicit: `raw_input()` seems to reproduce this problem.

Comment: So to clarify, the problem is with a Python shell embedded into this program?

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input`(and `input`, but that distinction seems not relevant here) is just reading from stdin. You can do that manually by reading from `sys.stdin`:

```
import sys
sys.stdin.read(1) # Read one character. '\n' means newline
sys.stdin.readline() # Read a single line, should be the same as raw_input()
```

If that does not work (i.e. sys.stdin.read(1) blocks too, even when you input something), the standard input may have been redirected by the host application (Flux in your case). You may be able to use an API of the host application to attach to it or get the input directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data you want in a file and call `open(".../file").read()` to read it.